# Изменение внешнего вида виджета

Tags: android, textview

Как изменить форму `ТеxtView` элемента?  У меня текст на полупрозрачном прямоугольном фоне. Как можно сделать прямоугольник другой фигурой?

Comment: Какая фигура нужна? Треугольник? Синусоида на боку? Десятиконечная звезда?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Все `View` в Android имеют xml-атрибут [`android:background`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background) (связанный метод: [`setBackgroundResource()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int))), который позволяет задать желаемый внешний вид виджета для всех возможных состояний: нормальное, нажатое, выделенное, неактивное, в фокусе, отмеченное и др. ([полный список](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html#lattrs)).

1.Для того, чтобы получить желаемый внешний вид виджета нужно подготовить, собственно, сам этот вид. Здесь возможны два варианта:

1. Изображение.
   Изображение внешнего вида виджета необходимо подготовить в каком то графическом редакторе для всех желаемых состояний: нормальное, нажатое, неактивное и другие, которые вам требуются (не обязательно все, те состояния, для которых вид не будет задан отрабатываться не будут - видимых изменений при этом состоянии вы не увидите).
   Так как наши виджеты имеют обычно заранее не определенные размеры ( то есть могут увеличиваться или уменьшаться в зависимости от расположенного на них контента, заданных размеров и тд.), то, как правило, изображения эти следует перевести в формат `9-patch` ( задать определенные области в которых изображение будет растягиваться, подстраиваясь под текущие размеры, а так же область, в которую будет выводиться контент.[Подробнее](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).)
   Если виджет имеет только фиксированный размер, то достаточно подготовить несколько  аналогичных изображений для разных плотностей экрана.[Подробнее](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).
   За этот способ выступает возможность получить сложный вид, ограниченный только фантазией художника.
2. Нарисовать с помощью графических примитивов xml-разметки. Для этого существует xml-атрибут [`shape`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)( bc соответствующий класс [`ShapeDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html)), который позволяет нарисовать точки, линии, прямоугольники, овалы и некоторое другое, а так же наложить заливку, градиенты, тени и тому подобное.
   За этот способ отличное масштабирование, малый размер и некоторое другое, вроде возможности изменять цвет динамически. В качестве недостатка относительная простота изображения.

Подготовленные файлы размещаются в папке `res/drawable/`, либо аналогичных с квалификаторами, если требуется.

2.После того, как внешний вид готов, нам необходимо создать специальный файл-селектор [`StateList`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList), который будет регулировать, каким изображениям\шейпам появляться при определенных состояниях виджета:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/widget_pressed" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/widget_normal" /> 
</selector>
```

Здесь задана обработка нажатия (`state_pressed`) - вся строка говорит: если на виджете фиксируется нажатие (состояние `true` - истина), то установить в качестве фона виджета изображение\шейп `widget_pressed`. 
Последним идет элемент без всяких условий - он соответствует нормальному виду виджета и будет выбран, когда никакое из состояний указанных ранее не было зафиксировано. Выполнение селектора идет сверху-вниз и будет закончено, когда первое попавшиеся сверху состояние совпадет с условием.
Данный файл так же распологается в `res/drawable/`

Если разные виды для определенных состояний не требуются и виджет всегда должен выглядеть одинаково и при касаниях и при неактивности и пр., то создание селектора можно ( и нужно) пропустить. Тогда в качестве фона используется статичное, заранее подготовленное изображение по технологии, описанной в пункте 1.

3.Завершающим штрихом будет установка созданного нами селектора (или статичного фона) (я назвал его `custom_background_selector`) в качестве фона виджета:

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="custom_background_selector"
  android:padding="12dp"
  android:text="Hello" />
```

Как правило, если делается кастомный вид для виджета, то этот виджет не один в приложении - тогда повторяющиеся атрибуты, в том числе и новый бэкграунд логично вынести в отдельный стиль (например, для кнопки):

**res/values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="styleMyButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button"> >
   <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_background_selector</item>
   <item name="android:padding">12dp</item>
   <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
   <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>
```

**res/layout/my_layout.xml**

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       style="@style/styleMyButton"
       android:text="@string/text_button1"/>

<Button
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       style="@style/styleMyButton"
       android:text="@string/text_button2"/>
```