# Одинаковые действия для разных View-элементов одного типа. Как упростить?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

**ЧТО У МЕНЯ ЕСТЬ**

У меня некое кол-во EditText'ов c TextChangedListener'ом  и ListView, который должен менять своё положение в зависимости от используемого EditText'а. Плюс к этому, OnItemClick для каждой position ListView должен устанавливать в используемый EditText соответствующий текст. Записать это получилось только так:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
MainActivity.this.adapter1.getFilter().filter(arg0);
        switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.editText1:
            top=editText1.getTop; right=editText1.getRight; 
        ListView.setX(right); ListView.setY(top);
lvFirst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position,long id) {
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            ListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            editText1.setText("case 0");
                            break;
                        ...
                     }
                }
            });
            break;
        case R.id.editText2:
            top=editText2.getTop; right=editText2.getRight; 
        ListView.setX(right); ListView.setY(top);
lvFirst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position,long id) {
                    switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                            ListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            editText2.setText("case 0");
                            break;
                        ...
                     }
                }
            });
            break;
        ...}
        }
```

Выглядит неприемлемо, но в качестве решения ничего кроме "велосипеда без колёс" придумать не удалось.

**ЧТО МНЕ НУЖНО**

Вообще мои EditText'ы - своего рода поисковые поля, через которые я ищу одно и то же: содержимое ListView, которое фильтруется в зависимости от вводимых символов в EditText'ы. Фильтр у меня работает. Все элементы ListView статичны. Текст, который появляется в EditText'е после нажатия на элемент ListView соответствует этому элементу.  По умолчанию ListView невидим, после ввода символов в какой-нибудь из EditText'ов он отображается и вот что:

скрин первый (мы начали вводить в editText1):

```
_______ <- это editText1 |это ListView|
_______ <- это editText2
```

скрин второй (мы начали вводить в editText2):

```
_______ <- это editText1 
_______ <- это editText2 |это ListView|
```

скрин третий (мы нажали на элемент ListView, называющийся "текст", с позицией 0 после того как начали вводить в editText1 слово "текст" и фильтр показал нам этот элемент):

```
_текст_ <- это editText1 |это ListView и он скрыт|
_______ <- это editText2
```

скрин третий (мы нажали на элемент ListView, называющийся "текст", с позицией 0 после того как начали вводить в editText2 слово "текст" и фильтр показал нам этот элемент):

```
_______ <- это editText1
_текст_ <- это editText2 |это ListView и он скрыт|
```

Comment: @pavlofff , готово, босс!

Comment: Почему вы не хотите использовать решения, заложенные в систему - `AutoCompleteTextView` или `SearchView` с автокомплитом, как например [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804805/android-action-bar-searchview-as-autocomplete) описывается?

Comment: @pavlofff , у меня этих EditText'ов аж 30 штук, распределённых по весу в TableLayout, что-то вроде книжного шкафа, хех. Я и начинал делать с SearchView, но мне не понравилось, что по  виду он не как EditText, там эта %@лупа, на которую нужно нажать, чтоб полосочка появилась, и полосочка эта c крестиком мерзким. Но в  общем-то,  с тех пор прошло уже много времени и я в принципе готов поморочиться, если только всё указанное мною выше в SearchView можно кастомить. Можно ли? И ещё кой-что. Для каких-то полей список совпадений не должен быть снизу, иначе он не поместится.

Comment: У меня складывается мнение, что вы пытаетесь заново придумать [AutoCompleteTextView](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm) - у него нет никаких луп с крестиками, автодополнение появляется на свободном месте экрана (если виджет внизу экрана, оно разворачивается вверх), по виду, как обычный `EditText`. Насчет кастомизации, есть ограничения, какие именно кастомные элементы вам нужны?

Comment: @pavlofff ,   я говорил про SearchView, AutoCompleteTextView не юзал, не знаю. Но если он без %@луп и крестиков, просто полосочкой и достаточно умный, чтобы появляться на свободном месте экрана, тогда это просто превосходно! Мне из кастома только  чтоб поле полосочкой, как я уже сказал, было, для подсказок цвет бэкграунда и, может, шрифт. Ну я уже погуглил, вроде всё возможно. Обидно, конечно, что заново всё делать, но мне полезно будет. В общем, спасибо! Ловите лайки!

Comment: @pavlofff , да всё уже ясно, спасибо! Если что ещё не понятно будет, напишу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для вашей задачи лучше использовать готовый виджет из SDK Android [`AutoCompleteTextView`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Виджет представляет собой поле ввода, аналогичное `EditText` при этом при вводе символов появляется выпадающий список с вариантами ввода, заранее заданными программно. При нажатии на один из появившихся пунктов он вносится в поле ввода.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   AutoCompleteTextView text;
   String[] languages={"Android ","java","IOS","SQL","JDBC","Web services"};

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      text=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

      ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,languages);

      text.setAdapter(adapter);
      text.setThreshold(1);

   }
}
```

метод `setThreshold()` устанавливает количество символов, после которого сработает автодополнение.

Возможности кастомизации:

Вы можете задать собственный вид для пунктов автодополнения, заменив системную разметку `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` собственной. Она обязательно должна содерхать виджет `TextView` с `android:id="@android:id/text1"` - в него бубт помещаться пункты.

Для более глубокой кастомизации вы можете написать собственный адаптер и реализовать почти любой вид пунктов.

Для кастомизации самого вида виджета `AutoCompleteTextView` смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345), действия для всех виджетов одинаковые.

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите onClickListener в отдельный интерфейс и привяжите этот интерфейс к вашим ListView. В интерфейсе обрабатывайте ваши EditText взависимости от ListView который вызывает интерфейс.