# Организовать поиск в базе населенных пунктов через Spinner

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста как организовать выбор населенного пункта через Spinner. Для добавления в профиль. Пользователь начинает набирать первые буквы своего населенного пункта и ему выпадает предлагаемый список из которого он выбирает свой населенный пункт. Нужно подтянуть ресурс из интернета

Comment: Возможно вам лучше использовать `AutoCompleteTextView` вместо `Spinner`.В качестве примера смотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/487198/177345)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.