# Как придавать View любую форму, чтобы можно было менять его цвет?

Tags: java, android, xml

К примеру, есть `ImageView` и его можно попытаться стилизовать через shape, но с помощью шейпов это не очень удобно и слишком мало вариантов.
Как можно обрезать любой вью и задать ему произвольную форму, чтобы потом программно можно было менять ему цвет?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с API 21 и с ревизии 23.2 библиотеки поддержки google, для поддержки устройств с API < 21, добавлен класс [`VectorDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html).

Вы можете нарисовать довольно сложный фон в SVG с помощью любого векторного редактора, вроде Inkscape. Android Studio преобразует изображение в формате SVG в формат `VectorDrawable` с помощью [встроенного инструмента *Vector Assets Studio*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html), затем вы можете использовать его в качестве фона, как и любой другой графический ресурс.

Вы можете менять цвет такого изображения с помощью свойств `android:tint` и `android:tintMode` (программно методы `setTint()`, `setTintMode()`), а так же метода `setColorFilter()`, в зависимости от желаемого результата.

О создании собственно произвольного вида для любого виджета смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345)