# Как сделать полоску в CardView

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такую полоску в CardView?

Comment: Установить  для `TextView` (или что это за виджет) бэкграунд с такой полосой снизу?

Comment: Это был совет, как решить проблему. Попробуем так - установите для виджетов фон с этой полоской. Как установить [бэкграунд для виджета](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345).

Comment: данный вопрос-картинку следует закрыть, так как ответ на него бесполезен для базы знаний, ведь поисковики (пока) не умеют индексировать смысл, выраженный картинкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/colorGray" />
```

Если надо добавляешь layout_margin

Answer (score 4):

Я обычно так делал, иногда на канве рисую у него даже есть флаги, мб такой вариант подойдет вам:

### drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="-2dp" android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/divider_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Дальше как обычно:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_divider"
```