# Как убрать поля вокруг текста у кнопки?

Tags: java, android

Хочу создать стиль для кнопки, чтобы в нем установить минимальные поля вокруг текста.
Как должен выглядеть код такого стиля?

Comment: Поля вокруг текста? Вы про отступы от границ кнопки?

Comment: Да, про отступы от границ кнопки!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345

Answer (score 0):

Используйте паддинг, например

```
android:padding="30dp"
```

Comment: Даже при установке в "0dp" поля остаются.

Comment: Попробуйте отрицательные значения

Comment: Скорее всего нужно найти стиль кнопки в андроиде