# Кастомизация TextView

Tags: android, textview

Как можно сделать такого вида TextView(его границы)?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли так деформировать границы элемента чтобы они выглядели как стрелки, по аналогии с Сss?

Comment: вы можете [нарисовать все, что угодно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345) в качестве фона любого виджета

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте nine patch. http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/draw9patch.php, вот вам ссылка.