# Создать селектор для LinearLayout с фоном

Tags: android

Есть фон

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать селектор для LinearLayout с этим фоном и чтобы в итоге получилось так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно в итоге получить разметку как на второй картинке. Чтобы она одинаково смотрелась на телефонах, планшетах. Желательно если возможно через xml. Векторное решение не хотелось бы использовать потому что они поддерживаются только с 5 версии андроид. Я пробовал такой вариант: Взял вторую картинку со скругленными углами и использовал ее в качестве фона для селектора. Но по краям у меня оставались пустые места некрасиво смотрелось. Собственно поэтому и решил спросить

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_bg_green">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/test2"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/test2"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_bg_light_blue">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:topRightRadius="@dimen/test2"
                android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/test2"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

делал так.

Comment: смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345) или пишите в вопросе подробнее, что именно из стандартной процедуры создания фона не получается.

Comment: Подробнее. Вопрос в следующем. Можно ли не используя картинки сделать такой же фон с округлыми краями? Т.е. чтобы по бокам был синий фон, который плавно переходит в белый?

Comment: Внес изменения в вопрос

Comment: `VectorDrawable` доступен начиная с Android 2.1 (API 7) через [библиотеку поддержки](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution) (подробности использования смотрите по ссылке). В векторе такой фон нарисовать вполне возможно.

Comment: Т.е. если я в gradle пропишу vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true, создам векторное изображение необходимое и переведу в xml, то будет работать? Но у меня тут возникает еще один вопрос. Как видите у меня градиент по бокам, а при переводе из SVG в VectorDrawable например тут http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/ нужный результат не получится, я и раньше пробовал. Места перехода градиента игнорировались или ошибку выдавало в разметке

Comment: А да, у VectorDrawable проблемы с градиентами и блюром. Насчет будет работать - должно, но надо пробовать, сам я этого не делал

Comment: Если бы градиента не было, полегче было бы. Но при градиенте перевод в VectorDrawable не сработает.

Comment: вам наверное лучше всего использовать 9-patch в такой ситуации, это намного проще

Comment: Я попробовал создать 9-patch картинку с закругленными углами размером высотой 800 шириной 1950 где-то, пикселей, но на планшетах углы криво смотрятся. вытянутые получаются в ширину

Comment: это очень большие размеры, нужно минимально необходимый размер, если это кнопка: высота где то 144 пикселя и длина примерно так-же, так как нужную длину 9-патч сам добавит из повторяющейся области, фактически должны быть только скругления

Comment: Нет, это не кнопка. Мне же для LianerLayout нужно. Там высоту для телефонов я указал 80dp, для планшетов 7 дюймов 120, а для планшетов 10 дюймов 160dp, а ширина match_parent