# Button со скруглёнными углами

Tags: android, button

У Button со скруглёнными углами после нажатия на неё пропадают скруглённые углы и прочие атрибуты. Что не так?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#F0A0F0" />
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>

        <gradient
            android:angle="45"
            android:centerX="35%"
            android:centerColor="#ffffff"
            android:startColor="#F0F0F0"
            android:endColor="#C0CF"
            android:type="linear"
            />
    </shape>
```

Пробовал ещё  State Drawables. Не помогло.

Подключение StateList:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/setWhiteFigure"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/states_button"

    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="@string/ustanovka"
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="5"

    android:visibility="visible"/>
```

xml файл описывающий состояния кнопки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:state_pressed="true">
</item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:state_checked="true">
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_button" >
    </item>
</selector>
```

Код, после которого скидывает button на простую форму:

```
      setWhiteFigure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener( ) {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
   TODO
}
```

Comment: смотрите в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345) пункт 2 про StateList. Вам нужно указать вид кнопки для состояния нажатия и проч.

Comment: StateList пробовал. Всё равно скидывает на обычную форму.

Comment: Лично меня смущает `android:state_checked`. Попробуйте без него или измените порядок - `state_pressed` в середину. А еще у вас нет параметра `android:shape="rectangle"`, что тоже может влиять на скругление углов и пр.

Comment: Если поменять местами или вообще убрать  'android:state_checked' ничего не меняется.

Comment: Может имеет значение, что я на эту кнопку вешаю onTouchListener и запускаю код в отдельном потоке?

Comment: Не ловко вышло. Не уследил, что в дальнейшем по цепочке методов я ещё менял эту кнопку. Вопрос рещён. Нужно удалить.

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий код кнопки с *ripple* эффектом и скругленными углами. Всего два состояния - нажата и по умолчанию. Может поможет разобраться.

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="@color/pressed_color">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

Comment: Нет. Скидывает.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать указать drawable для не нажатого состояния:

```
<item
        android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:state_pressed="false">
</item>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но я уже разобрался. Это была просто моя ошибка.