# Как сделать на android кнопки четверть от круга

Tags: java, android, xml, button

Мне нужно сделать такие кнопки, как это сделать на android[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: отвечу банально) - нарисовать. Просто такой результат возможен, разными путями, нужно знать детали использования кнопок. Самый быстрый используйте ImageView с одинаковым размером -> вставляйте вектор, для второй картинки флипнуть вектор, или саму ImageView

Comment: что значит "вставить вектор в ImageView"?

Comment: На картинке у вас не четверть круга, а четверть "остроугольного овала"). Нужно именно то, что на картинке или всё же четверть круга?

Comment: использовать векторное изображение вместо растрового, в андройде за это отвечает класс VectroDrawable.  Создаем ImageView и делаем set.  imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.vector).
Опять же вопрос из тех, что проще нарисовать чем объяснять))

Comment: просто устанавливайте кнопкам [такой бэкграунд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345) и все/ Нарисовать можете как считаете удобным:простая png, xml-shape, VectorDrawable