# Выделение ячеек в GridView?

Tags: java, android

ячейку при нажатии,какой обработчик  делает жто?

Comment: вам нужно сделать [xml-selector для айтема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345) (пункт 2 в ответе) и назначить его бэграундом айтему