# Двустрочный текст в кнопке

Tags: android-studio, android-button

Как сделать двухстрочный текст в кнопке? Цифры будут динамически меняться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вмето кнопки используйте, например, LinearLayout. назначте ему нужный фон, расположите виджеты TextView как вам надо и повешайте на этот лэйаут слушатель - кнопка готова

Comment: для реализации реакции на действия, как клик, на фон назначьте xml - selector. Смотрите ответ как [оформить виджет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345).

Comment: Благодарю за советы) И как сам не сообразил, ведь делал нечто подобно) Еще раз спасибо)