# Ошибка при попытке кастомизировать кастомную FAB android

Tags: android, android-button

Я нашел FAB-кнопку на просторах гитхаба по этой [ссылке](https://github.com/yavski/fab-speed-dial) вы сможете ее увидеть. Вроде кнопка прекрасная, но все-равно возникло желание что-то изменить. Я хотел изменить картинку на кнопке после нажатия, то есть до нажатия одна картинка, а после - другая. 
Вот код кнопки в разметке:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <io.github.yavski.fabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial
            android:id="@+id/fab_but_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:fabGravity="bottom_end"
            app:fabDrawable = "@drawable/ic_settings_cogwheel"
            app:fabMenu="@menu/main_screen_menu_fab"
            app:miniFabDrawableTint="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:miniFabTitleTextColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Если я правильно понял, то нужно использовать эту строку в xml файле:

```
app:fabDrawableTint
```

Мне показалось что эта функция будет показывать новую картинку, то есть заменять одну картинку на другую, после нажатия на кнопку. Но как результат, я получил ошибку:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.developer_4.test_login/com.example.developer_4.test_login.SecondScreenActivity.MainScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class io.github.yavski.fabspeeddial.FabSpeedDial
```

Вроде как понятно что ошибка в вставленной мною строке, потому-что без этой строки приложение хотя-бы работает. Но я не могу понять какая тогда функция отвечает за изменение картинки после нажатия на кнопку?

Comment: никакакой xml-атрибут не отвечает за изменение картинки после нажатия. Вы должны делать это сами: программно, обрабатывая клик или изменив [xml-селектор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345) (пункт 2.0 ответа), который обрабатывает клики. атрибуты с *tint* вообще используются для окрашивания (колорирования) изображения и в качестве аргумента принимают цвет

Comment: @pavlofff, честно говоря из всего что вы перечислили мне самым простым показалось программное изменение но и оно почему-то не работает. пробую сделать изменение если выполнено условие: `fabSpeedDial.isEnabled()` но походу это не то условие :)

Comment: вот [селектор той кнопки](https://github.com/yavski/fab-speed-dial/blob/master/library/src/main/res/drawable/fab_add_clear_selector.xml), что используется по дефолту в библиотеке, вы можете изменить его, подставив свои ресурсы изображений и назначив свой селектор в качестве бэкграунда кнопке

Comment: да но если я правильно понял, номерки возле ресурса это секунды или что-то типа того, ведь там анимация нужна как-бы

Comment: смотрите библиотеку, как все реализовано там. сами картинки от 0 до 9 в папке drawable-xxxhdpi

Comment: а условие там не enabled, a selected

Comment: ок я кажись начинаю постепенно понимать как это сделать, спасибо что натолкнули на мысль, буду пробовать :)