# Форма TextView XML

Tags: android, xml

Прошу понять меня правильно: Я не прошу что-то сделать за меня и предоставить готовый код

ВОПРОС: Какие атрибуты необходимо использовать, чтобы выполнить такой же вид как на скрине, указанный стрелкой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно вам подойдёт: `android:background="@drawable/background`

Comment: это [нарисованный фон](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345), а не атрибуты виджета.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого вам следует сделать свой drawable такой же формы и установить его как фон TextView