# Рамка вокруг элементов

Tags: android

Надо реализовать такой участок в приложении на android, как сделать такую же
рамку вокруг иконки комментариев и счетчика? Что это за view?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [изменение внешнего вида виджетов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345)

Answer (score 0):

Само поле - `TextView` с `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"`

Рамка - обычный `drawable`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <corners android:radius="3dp" />
     <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#999"/>
     <size android:width="5dp" android:height="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Выставленный как `textView.setBackgroundResource(my_back)`.