# Как убрать скругленные углы у кнопок в Android?

Tags: android

Android по умолчанию делает скругленные края у кнопки. Не могу понять как это скругление убрать.

Comment: Кнопки разные бывают) Если MaterialButton - то это довольно сложно. Если просто Button - то просто сложно)

Comment: Простой Button у меня

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424968/177345

Answer (score 2):

Изготовьте drawable которая будет являться внешним видом вашей кнопки. Задайте ей необходимые параметры (фон, закругление углов и прочее). Например:

**back.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="#999999"
    />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#000000">
</stroke>
```

Ну и потом добавьте к вашей кнопке :

```
<Button
android:background="@drawable/back"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_parent" />
```

Comment: Этак пропадут эффекты нажатия на кнопку. Чтобы не пропадали - надо, вроде, LayerList сделать, где будут отдельные Shape под каждое состояние

Comment: @ЮрийСПб хорошее замечание)

Comment: Что за "@drawable/back"? У меня ошибку выдает ( P.S. Понял ) а что за LayerList?

Comment: @rusikus, перепутал с selector - посмотрите по ссылке в комменте pavlofff под вопросом)